# Point multiplication twice - can it be squeezed into one equation?

Tags: elliptic-curves

```
p_1 := (d_1)G
p_2 := (d_2)p_1
```

$P_2$ is calculated as shown above. Will $P_2$ be the same of $P_2$ in the second equation?

```
p_2 := ((d_1 * d_2) % curve_order)G
```

If I understand correctly, it shouldn't have any problems with the point at infinity. Are there any differences between two ways to calculate the point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, on an elliptic curve $\mathcal C$, we can use that $\forall d_1\in\Bbb Z, \forall d_2\in\Bbb Z, \forall G\in\mathcal C$
$$\begin{align}
d_2\times(d_1\times G)&=(d_2\cdot d_1)\times G\\
&=(d_2\cdot d_1\bmod n)\times G
\end{align}$$
where $n$ is the order of the curve, and also for $n$ the order of $G$ (which divides the order of the curve). That more generally holds in any finite group $(\mathcal C,+)$ with scalar multiplication $\times$ defined from the group law $+$ (even if not commutative).

For $d_1$ and $d_2$ random in $[0,n)$, the form $(d_2\cdot d_1\bmod n)\times G$ will typically be fastest, for decent implementation of the modular multiplication. It is best to use $n$ the order of $G$ (which can be smaller than the order of the curve). Beware that the modular multiplication could lead to a [side channel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side-channel_attack).

If $d_1\times G=\infty$ with $G\ne\infty$, and the implementation of $d\times X$ fails when $X=\infty$, then both $(d_2\cdot d_1)\times G$ and $(d_2\cdot d_1\bmod n)\times G$ will prevent that failure (the end result will be $\infty$ all the same and the implementation should be able to deal with this). If the implementation fails when it internally encounters $\infty$ in some internal operation, the change in method of computation can potentially remove or create the condition triggering the issue; that depends on internals.

I have used $\cdot$ for integer multiplication, and $\times$ for point multiplication by scalar/integer.